# The latest two status of sql server agent jobs

Tags: sql-server, sql-agent-job

I need to make a query that gets the the status of sql server agent jobs.

The tricky part, is that I both want the time the job last have failed (if any) AND when it last ran successful - is that possible?

So far I have only been able to get the last successful run or the last failed run of a job.

```
SELECT 
job.name
,jobh.run_date 
,DATEADD(HOUR, (jobh.run_time / 1000000) % 100, 
DATEADD(MINUTE, (jobh.run_time / 10000) % 100,
DATEADD(SECOND, (jobh.run_time / 100) % 100,
DATEADD(MILLISECOND, (jobh.run_time % 100) * 10, 
cast('00:00:00' as TIME(0)))))) AS 'tidspunkt'
,jobh.run_duration
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory jobh
JOIN [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs] job ON jobh.job_id = job.job_id
WHERE jobh.step_id = 0
AND jobh.message LIKE '%failed%'
AND (jobh.run_date = CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112) OR jobh.run_date =    CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()), 112) )
AND job.name = 'UpdateCPR'
ORDER BY jobh.run_date DESC, jobh.run_time DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the line...

```
AND jobh.message LIKE '%failed%'
```

...to following...

```
AND (jobh.message LIKE '%failed%' OR jobh.message LIKE '%succeeded%')
```

You will get multiple rows. If you wish, you can group that by LIKE result and select TOP 1 from both to retrieve it in one row.

**EDIT**

Use this to get both fail and success info in one row.

```
;WITH jobRuns AS (
    SELECT
        job.job_id,
        job.name,
        jobh.run_time,
        jobh.run_duration,
        execStatus
    FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory jobh
    JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs job 
        ON jobh.job_id = job.job_id
    CROSS APPLY(
        SELECT execStatus = CASE 
            WHEN jobh.message LIKE '%failed%' THEN 0 
            WHEN jobh.message LIKE '%succeeded%' THEN 1 END) ext
    WHERE 
        jobh.step_id = 0
        and job.name LIKE '%testjob%'
    /*GROUP BY
        job.job_id,
        job.name,
        jobh.run_time,
        execStatus*/)
,lastRuns AS (
    SELECT TOP 1
        jobRuns.job_id,
        jobRuns.name,
        run_time_failed = failed.run_time,
        run_duration_failed = failed.run_duration,
        run_time_succeeded = success.run_time,
        run_duration_succeeded = success.run_duration
    FROM jobRuns
    CROSS APPLY(
        SELECT TOP 1 run_time, run_duration
        FROM jobRuns
        WHERE execStatus = 0
        ORDER BY run_time DESC) failed
    CROSS APPLY(
        SELECT TOP 1 run_time, run_duration
        FROM jobRuns
        WHERE execStatus = 1
        ORDER BY run_time DESC) success
)
SELECT * 
FROM lastRuns
```

Comment: How would you do that group by thing, on the query above to the both the fail and success status in one row?